# Alamofire & Swift - Query and return JSON data based on a values

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am trying to create a method to return JSON objects using parameters.

I'll explain further, and how my application works.

Firstly, the user enters a product i.e. "MacBook", the user then presses the search button on the keyboard and all products with the name "MacBook" are returned and populated into a UITableView.

When the user selects a row, the data is passed to the next view controller i.e. "DetailViewController". The DetailedViewController has variables i.e. var productStock, var productPrice, var productBrand etc.

All the information is displayed and the app, so far, is working as planned.

However, I wish to create a method which can take certain parameters i.e. productBrand and productName. And search the whole API and return results which match the criteria, within the DetailsViewController. For example (pseudo-code)

```
var minimumStockAmount = 1

var productPrice: Int!

var url = "www.testapi.com/products"

func callApiWithParameters(productStock, productPrice) {
 Alamofire.request((url), parameters: productBrand, productPrice) {
   if productStock >= minimumStockAmount  {
    return productStock //This will return stock which is at-least 1
}

if price = productPrice - 20 {
   return price //This is get items from the API where the price is the current product price minus 20. e.g. productPrice = 30, minus 20 will be 10. Should return any/all items in the API with a price of 10.
}

}
```

If there is any confusion, please tell me I will help to clarify. In essence, it's similar to when using SQL/SQLite the the `SELECT * WHERE` command(s).

Comment: I believe this method requires a dictionary for the parameters. [String: Any].